# Set folder permissions with C# - convert CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") from vb to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'd like to know how to convert this vb script to C#

```
Dim strFolder As String
Dim objShell As Object

strFolder = "C:\zz"

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

objShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /c Echo Y| cacls " & _
                 strFolder & _
                 " /t /c /g everyone:F ", 2, True
```

What I'm trying to do is set permissions to "Everyone" on a newly created folder on the users C:\ drive.

I'm using Visual Studio, .Net 1.1

Thanks.
Iain

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to upgrade unfortunately - I work for a big company, so would mean updating loads of people - which would be a mission...

But - creating a process worked!

```
System.Diagnostics.Process meProc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ("cmd.exe", " /c echo y| cacls C:\\zzz /t /c /g everyone:F");
```

Thanks both of you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is upgrading to a newer version not possible?  .NET 2.0 introduced classes in the [System.Security.AccessControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.aspx) namespace to handle this.  If it's really not possible and you only have this one command to execute, you may want to create a [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) and just execute the `cacls` command in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is also using the "Microsoft.Win32.Security" library...

I've no SecuredObject

```
SecuredObject sec = new SecuredObject("C:\\", SecuredObjectType.FileObject);
```